# Lambda times-out when trying to write to SNS, how can I fix this in Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-sns, amazon-vpc, terraform-provider-aws

I have a lambda inside of a VPC that needs to write to an SNS topic. I understand that I need a `aws_vpc_endpoint` to make this work.

However, my lambda still times-out when trying to write to SNS.

```hcl
data "aws_vpc_endpoint_service" "sns" {
  service = "sns"
}

resource "aws_security_group" "sns_endpoint" {
  name   = "sns-endpoint"
  vpc_id = aws_default_vpc.default.id
}

resource "aws_vpc_endpoint" "sns_endpoint" {
  vpc_id              = aws_default_vpc.default.id
  vpc_endpoint_type   = "Interface"
  service_name        = data.aws_vpc_endpoint_service.sns.service_name
  security_group_ids  = [ aws_security_group.sns_endpoint.id ]
  private_dns_enabled = true

  subnet_ids = [
    data.aws_subnet.selected.id,
    aws_default_subnet.subnet_a.id,
    aws_default_subnet.subnet_b.id
  ]

  policy  = <<EOF
      {
        "Statement": [
          {
            "Sid": "SNS-full-access",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "sns:*",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*"
          }
        ]
      }
    EOF
}

resource "aws_security_group" "my_func" {
  name        = "my-func"
  vpc_id      = aws_default_vpc.default.id

  egress {
    from_port       = 0
    to_port         = 65535
    protocol        = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks     = [ "0.0.0.0/0" ]
  }
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "my_func" {
  function_name    = "my-func"
  role             = aws_iam_role.my_func.arn
  timeout          = 900
  memory_size      = 512

  vpc_config {
    subnet_ids         = [ data.aws_subnet.selected.id ]
    security_group_ids = [ aws_security_group.my_func.id ]
  }
}
```

DNS hostnames and DNS resolution are enabled for the VPC.

**What am I missing here?**

Comment: Please add the `aws_security_group.sns_endpoint` configuration to your question. Also, is DNS support enabled on the VPC?

Comment: Might a VPC Flow Log help you determine where the SNS traffic is being dropped?

Comment: @MarkB The security group is empty. DNS hostnames and resolution are enabled for the VPC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An empty security group is going to block all access by default. You need to update the endpoint's security group to allow access from the Lambda function:

```
resource "aws_security_group" "sns_endpoint" {
  name   = "sns-endpoint"
  vpc_id = aws_default_vpc.default.id

  ingress {
    from_port       = 0
    to_port         = 65535
    protocol        = "tcp"
    security_groups = [aws_security_group.my_func.id]
  }
}
```

I think you might be able to lock that down to just port `443`, but try the above first to see if it clears up your issue.

Comment: Can confirm only `443` is required.